# How to return documents where two fields have same value

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to find only those documents in a collections with same value in two given fields?

```
{
    _id:    'fewSFDewvfG20df', 
    start:  10,
    end:    10
}
```

As here `start` and `end` have the same value, this document would be selected.

I think about something like...

```
Collection.find({ start: { $eq: end } })
```

... which wouldn't work, as `end` has to be a value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options here. The first one is to use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

```js
Collection.find( { $where: "this.start === this.end" } )
```

The second option is to use the aggregation framework and the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator.

```js
Collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$start", "$end" ] },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

> Which one is better?

The `$where` operator does a JavaScript evaluation and can't take advantage of indexes so query using `$where` can cause a drop of performance in your application. See [considerations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations). If you use $where each of your document will be converted from BSON to JavaScript object before the $where operation which, will cause a drop of performance. Of course your query can be improved if you have an index filter. Also There is security risk if you're building your query dynamically base on user input.

The `$redact` like the `$where` doesn't use indexes and even perform a collection scan, but your query performance improves when you `$redact` because it is a standard MongoDB operators. That being said the aggregation option is far better because you can always filter your document using the $match operator.

`$where` here is fine but could be avoided. Also I believe that you only need `$where` when you have a schema design problem. For example adding another boolean field to the document with index can be a good option here.

Comment: can this one use used in array elements?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) in mongodb **3.6** to match the two fields from the same document.

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": ["$start", "$end"] } })
```

or with aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$start", "$end"] }}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

this query is fast, since least function calls are involved,

```
Collection.find("this.start == this.end");
```