# Find By Array Elements Comparison

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection called test:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5887a9202d599801b7df2c3c"), "name" : "soccer66", "ratings" : [ 5, 3.2, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5887a9232d599801b7df2c3d"), "name" : "user1", "ratings" : [ 2, 3.2, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5887a9262d599801b7df2c3e"), "name" : "user2", "ratings" : [ 2.5, 4.9, 1 ] }
```

What's the optimal way to select the documents where the first rating is greater than the second?  I've tried lots of queries.  For the sake of this post I ran the following again:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
         {$project:{"isGreater":{$cond:[{$gt:["$ratings.0","$ratings.1"]},true,false]}}},
         {$match:{"isGreater": true}}]);
>

> db.test.find({$where: "this.ratings.0" < "this.ratings.1"});
```

> ```
> Error: error: {
>   "ok" : 0,
>   "errmsg" : "$where got bad type",
>   "code" : 2,
>   "codeName" : "BadValue"
> }
> ```
>
> db.test.find({"ratings.0": {"$gt": "ratings.1"}});

Proof I'm using the correct array index with ratings.#:

```
> db.test.find({"ratings.0":5});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5887a9202d599801b7df2c3c"), "name" : "soccer66", "ratings" : [ 5, 3.2, 1 ] }
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Do not use the `$where` operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138963/how-to-return-documents-where-two-fields-have-same-value)

You should use the Aggregation Framework for this.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ratings.1": { "$exists": true } } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$gt": [
                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$ratings", 0 ] },
                { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$ratings", 1 ] }
            ]},
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Styvane!  Accepted this through the reasoning in your link.

Answer (score 4):

In your `$where` statement whole "where" predicate should be in quotes:

```
db.test.find({$where: "this.ratings[0] < this.ratings[1]"});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!  Upvoted for the super-fast reply and conciseness (although it may not be optimal haha).